# I - plural or singular?

Tags: verb-forms, subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

Which one is correct ? I *were* or I *was*

We always use I *have* which implies that ***I*** is plural.

Then why don't we use I *are*  ?

Comment: How many of you are there? I don't understand why you would think that I is plural. Is your confusion about "have"? It would help if you explained your thinking a bit more.

Comment: **Either** *I was* or *I were* could be correct. It is impossible to tell you which is correct based on the two words alone. Could you provide a sample sentence or two? Also, *have* can be an *auxiliary* verb or a 'regular' verb, so if you provide example sentences... that would make answering the question easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I have* does not imply that *I* is plural; it implies only that *I* is not 3rd person singular (3sg).

*Be* is the ***only*** English verb which has distinct forms for the 1st person singular (1sg): *am* in the present indicative and *was* in the past indicative.

All other English verbs, including *HAVE*, have

- in the present, at most two forms<sup>‡</sup>, one for third person singular  and a 'general' one for all other persons in either singular or plural
- in the past, a single 'general' form for all persons and numbers

Here are the forms for *BE*, *HAVE*, and a representative 'regular' verb *PLAY*; forms for specific persons and numbers are marked with a * (but see the footnote).

      `VERB:          BE      HAVE      PLAY
    PRESENT
      general form:  are     have     play
          1sg form:  am*     (same)   (same)
          3sg form:  is*     has*     plays*
    PAST 
      general form:  were    had      played
    1sg & 3sg form:  was*    (same)   (same)`

<sup>‡</sup> <sub>Modal verbs have only one; they do not have a distinct 3sg form</sub> 
<sup>∗</sup> <sub>Note that even these are not used in what traditional grammar calls  "subjunctive" clauses—but that is another matter.</sub>

Comment: Then why dont we use "I has" ?

Comment: @Vinayak Because "I" is 1st person singular. Only 3d person singular takes *has*: subjects which are neither the person speaking nor the person addressed. *He, she, it, William Wycherley, the Man in the Iron Mask*.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, English's conjugation system is not as fine-grained (that is, not as detailed) as many other languages. In particular, in general* the conjugations for first person (single and plural), second person (single and plural), and third person plural are all the same: I have, you have, we have, you all have, they have; I jump, you jump, we jump, you all jump, they jump. The one case that conjugates differently is *third person* singular: she has, he jumps.

*There are exceptions: for example "to be" conjugates differently in the first person singular: I am, you are, she is, we are, you all are, they are. But note that the second person singular and all the plural forms are still the same.